# angular image tag is loading with a delay

Tags: angular

I have a template like :

```
<div *ngIf="showSpinner">
   <img src="spinner.gif">
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="showSpinner">
     Test
 </div>
```

When `showSpinner` is set in the method which spawns lot of ajax calls, the `Test` is displayed immediately but image comes up after a delay in the range of 10-15 seconds or maybe more. What could be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're observing, where the text "Test" is displayed immediately but the image takes longer to appear, could be due to several factors. Here's an examination of potential causes:

1. **Image Size:** If the image spinner.gif is large in file size, it might take a while to download, especially if the user's internet
   connection is slow. If this is the case, try compressing the image
   or using a smaller, optimized version.
2. **Rendering Behavior:** Browsers will typically render text almost
   instantaneously, as it doesn't need to be downloaded like an image.
   Even if both the text and the image are linked to the same condition
   (showSpinner), the text will appear first as it doesn't rely on a
   network request.
3. **Preloading Strategy:** If loading the spinner image quickly is
   critical, you could consider preloading the image. By telling the
   browser to load the image in advance, it's more likely to be ready
   by the time it's needed. You can do this using the  tag in the HTML head,
   or by using JavaScript to load the image early in the page
   lifecycle.

Without more specific details about the situation (such as the network conditions, browser behavior, server setup, etc.), it's hard to pinpoint the exact cause of the delay.